# Creating one csv file containing data from many csv files

Tags: python

I have a folder full of csv files that contain results for different participants in an experiment. I'm trying to create one large csv file containing all the csv files in the directory. I'm using listdir() to create a list of all the files but I haven't been able to open the individual files in this list. I think I need to loop over each file but I haven't been able to figure out how.

This is the code I've come up with so far. I get the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'results_262.csv' because it appears that the loop only reads one file in the files variable even though there should be many.

```
from os import listdir
path = "results"
files = listdir(path)
print(files)
results = open("results.csv", "w")

data = []
for file in files:
    participant = open(f"{file}", "r")
    data.append(participant.readlines())
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Could you provide details about your folder and the files inside, for example a result of the `tree` shell command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `listdir()` returns the filenames without their path information, so you need to append the filename to the path.

```
import os
...

for file in files:
    participant = open(os.join(path, file), "r"):
    ...
```

Other details:

`f"{file}"` is the same thing as just `file`. I.e., `open(file, "r")` is equivalent to `open(f"{file}", "r")`, but more efficient - there is not need to use interpolation what you already have the value you want in a variable.

And, you're not closing your files. You should add `participant.close()` in your loop, or, even better, use a context manager:

```
for file in files:
    with open(os.join(path, file), "r") as participant:
        ...
```

The `with` puts your file handle in a context manager, and the file gets closed automatically when you leave the scope of the context manager.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to do what you said but I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matthiasbirkholz/Desktop/Year 3/PSYC0157 Computer Programming/Coursework1/Coursework1/trial.py", line 11, in <module>
    data.append(participant.readlines())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 27: invalid start byte

Comment: Now, that's a different problem. When you open the file, you need to know what encoding they're using. Are they in utf-8 or something else? Add the `encoding="<encoding>"` parameter to specify it. E.g., `open(os.join(path, file), "r", encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: Or `encoding="latin-1"` or whatever the correct answer is for your data. You need to do the same thing when you're opening your output file for writing. The error you got is because Python is assuming utf-8 on your computer, but your data is (presumably) in some other encoding.